# Why HttpServletRequest getParameter() have different behavior with POST/GET

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

I just occurred an issue related to getParameter()
I send a POST request like:

http://localhost:7001/test?get=%2B

with post body like:

```
{
    "post": "%2B"
}
```

And when I use `request.getParameter()` method to retrieve result, the "get" one returns `+` and the "post" on returns `%2B`. It looks like the `getParameter` would decode param from url automatically. For post request, it doesn't work at all. I wander what's the proper way to retrieve value from `get` and `post`. Thanks!

Comment: That's not true. The real answer depends on the way how you send the POST request. Apparently it's also encoding the parameters for you before sending it, which in turn means that you don't need to manually encode them beforehand ;)

Comment: Capture the HTTP traffic and compare both requests to be sure they send the parameters in the same way.

Comment: Indeed. You'll then see that POST is sending `%252B` instead of `%2B` ;)